# Ext js4 form doesn't read json output

Tags: php, forms, extjs4

I just started learning extjs and was trying my hands on login form. But couldn't find much material to read and get a login form working. The form I tried creates fields, takes submited form on login.php. But instead of executing "success:" "failure:" , it prints json code on login.php and when i tries to print the submitted code using prin_r($_POST), it returns blank value  .

Here is code from app.js

```
Ext.require('Ext.container.Viewport');

Ext.application({
name : 'userApp',
appFolder : 'app',

launch : function() {
    console.log("random stuff ");
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout : 'fit',
        items : [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            id: 'userLogin',
            title: 'User Login',
            name: 'loginform',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Username',
                name: 'username',
                allowBlank: false,
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                name: 'password',
                allowBlank: false,
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Login',
                url: 'login.php',
                handler: function(obj){
                    form = obj.getParent().getParent();
                    form.submit({
                        url: 'login.php',
                        method: 'POST',
                        success: function() {
                            console.log(arguments);
                            alert("sss");
                        },
                        failure: function() {
                            console.log(arguments);
                            alert("ssssssss");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }]
        }]
    });
}
});
```

and login.php is

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
if(isset($_REQUEST['username']) && isset($_REQUEST['password'])){
    if($_REQUEST['username'] == "neelam" && $_REQUEST['password'] == "neelam"){
        echo '{"success": true}';
    }
}
echo '{"success": false}';
?>
```

Please send links of CRUD tutorial of extjs4 + php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following line:

```
form = obj.getParent().getParent();
```

to:

```
form = obj.up('userLogin');
```

also, you might want to add a die(); after the following line in your php code as otherwise you will get success and failure responses even in case of success.

```
echo '{"success": true}';
die();
```

and don't forget to remove the print_r() before you test it :)